# Identifying ActionBar Options Menu items uniquely

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm in the process of converting an app I originally wrote to target v2.2 so it targets v4 using the v4 compatibility library and ActionBarSherlock.

I'm playing around with the `ActionBar` Options menu and sub-menus and trying to work out how to identify sub-menu items in a unique fashion.

Example...

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    SubMenu mediaSubMenu = menu.addSubMenu("Media");
    mediaSubMenu.add("Videos");
    mediaSubMenu.add("Music");

}
```

That's fine and I get an `ActionBar` menu item for "Media" and when I click I see the "Videos" and "Music" sub-menu items. My problem is the only way I've worked out to identify the sub-menu item which was clicked is as follows...

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    if (item.getTitle().equals("Music")) {
        // Do something
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It occurs to me though that I might have another sub-menu item with the same name, for example, "Settings" -> "Music".

How do I differentiate between the two? I can't help feeling I'm missing something very simple here.

Comment: Why not use the [`add`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#add(int,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) method that allows you to specify an Id?

Comment: And there you go - I knew it would be something simple. I was too busy concentrating on `onOptionsItemSelected(...)` and didn't think about the `add(...)`. Doh!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set ids for your MenuItems

```
mediaSubMenu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.media_videos, Menu.NONE, "Videos")
```

you can define the id in a resource file (like res/values/ids.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="media_videos" type="id"/>
    <item name="other_videos" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

and you can then use

```
switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.media_videos:
        ...
    case R.id.other_videos:
        ...
}
```

I'd also recommend using the menu xml to set up your action bar data.

Comment: Thank you. I knew it would be something simple, and I will be using menu.xml eventually but hard-coded a few things for test purposes.